# Basic question about multilinear forms

Tags: differential-geometry, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space on a field $\mathbb{K}$. Let $(V^\ast)^{\otimes q}$ be the space of $q$-linear forms, $\Lambda^q(V^\ast)$ the space of skew-symmetric multilinear forms and $Sym^q(V^\ast)$ the space of symmetric multilinear forms.

I proved that
$$
(V^\ast)^{\otimes 2}=\Lambda^2(V^\ast)\oplus Sym^2(V^\ast) 
$$
by using the isomorphism $(V^\ast)^{\otimes 2}\cong gl(\mathbb{K},n)$.

I'd like to generalize for $q\ge 3$, but I don't have any ideas

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $\oplus$ instead of $\otimes$ on the right hand side?

Comment: Yes! You are right

Comment: This is in general a little complicated. For $k = 3$, we have
$$(V^*)^{\otimes 3} \cong \Lambda^3 V^* \oplus H \oplus H' \oplus S^3 V^*$, where $H$ and $H'$ are isomorphic spaces of $3$-tensors with what are sometimes called *hook symmetry*. More generally, one can give a combinatorial description of the decomposition of $(V^*)^(\otimes k)$, which is maybe best understood in terms of Young diagrams. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau

Comment: Certainly $(V^*)^{\otimes 2}$ cannot be $GL(\Bbb K,n)$, as the latter is not a vector space.

Comment: I mean just the square matrices, not the invertible ones. Which is the standard notation for them? Sorry for the misunderstanding and thanks for the remark :)

Comment: i'm reediting $$(V^*)^{\otimes 3} \cong \Lambda^3 V^* \oplus H \oplus H' \oplus S^3 V^*$$ to see it better